# The definition "module of finite type".

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I know the definition of "module of finite type"

Is that different from finitely generated module ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This term is sometimes used to mean a finitely generated module. That is to say, if someone says ``an $R$-module of finite type," he or she definitely means finitely generated as a module. I think that nowadays it is more common to say "finitely generated $R$-module," or, especially in commutative algebra, "finite $R$-module." I prefer this terminology. Of course the latter could lead to confusion in principle, but not usually in practice. In the contexts of $R$-algebras, an $R$-algebra *of finite type* is definitely not the same thing as an $R$-algebra that is finitely generated as an $R$-module (often just called a finite $R$-algebra).

Answer (score 0):

*finite type* means  finitely generated $R$- algebra
*finite* means finitely generated $R$-module
so in *Atiyah-Macdonald*'s famous book this proposition
[image]

results

[image]

Comment: You're talking about algebras, the OP is talking about modules.

Comment: im talking about difference of finite type and finite