# How to prove a finite module (finitely generated module) is finite type?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

A $R$-module $S$ is finite, or finitely generated as a module over $R$, if there is an onto homomorphism of $R$-modules from the free $R$-module on a finite set to $S$

$$R^{\oplus n} \twoheadrightarrow S$$

$S$ is finite type, or finitely generated as an algebra over $R$, if there is an onto homomorphism of $R$-algebras from the free $R$-algebra on a finite set to $S$

$$R[x_1, \dots, x_n] \twoheadrightarrow S$$

How to prove finite $\Rightarrow$ finite type?

Comment: The first definition is about modules, and the second definition is about $R$ algebras.  How does it make sense to ask the final implication? Are you sure you didn't mean something more like what appears [in this post?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/757733/29335)

Comment: I am asking if a R-algebra S is finite as a R-module, how to show R is finite type.

Comment: Just read through your definitions again, there's nothing special going on here, it is just a logical consequence. If $S$ is generated by $s_1,\dots, s_n$ $\in S$, as an $R$-module then it is ofcourse generated by the same set as an $R$-algebra. For an $R$-algebra, being finite is strictly stronger than being finite type. For example the $R$-algebra $R[x]$ is clearly finite type but not finite.